# How can Set's internal order could be broken?

Tags: java, data-structures, set

Every Java doc says that Set is unordered data structure.
But when we are trying some experiments like that:

```java
public class SetTest {

    @Test
    public void testIterationsOverSet() {
        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            s.add(i);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.toArray()));
        }

        Set<Integer> s2 = new LinkedHashSet<>(s);

        Set<Integer> s3 = new TreeSet<>(s2);

        printSet(s, "HashSet");

        printSet(s2, "LinkedHashSet");

        printSet(s3, "TreeSet");

    }

    private void printSet(Set<Integer> set, String msg) {
        System.out.println("\n"+msg);
        Iterator<Integer> itr = set.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(itr.next());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

We will get output like this:

```sh
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

HashSet
0123456789

LinkedHashSet
0123456789

TreeSet
0123456789
```

Order of a variety of sets is the in the output above. I've had a hypothesis that, every time we change the Set by adding new element to it, we will crush we would change the order, but everything seems to be ordered inside of the Set, elements stored as they were added.

So in reality it's said, that order is just not guaranteed, and the example above is correct, and everything works as expected.

But the question is, in what cases we could break the order inside of the Set?

Comment: *"in what cases?"* There are a gazillion cases, but for now, try simply starting at some higher value, e.g. change loop to `for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)` and you'll get `HashSet: 16171819101112131415`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash set isn't sorting the numbers you're inserting, but it happens to *retain the insertion order in this specific case* because you're inserting a contiguous set of numbers starting from 0. By mere happenstance, this is a set of numbers that ends up not being scrambled.

The reason is that an integer's hash code is the integer itself, and hash codes map directly to the indices in the hash map's internal array. 0 is inserted at index 0, 1 at index 1, 2 at index 2, and so on. When you insert consecutive small integers you're essentially testing the simplest possible scenario, one where the hash map's behavior is in fact quite predictable.

Try more complicated scenarios: instead of 0-9, insert 100-109; or 100-200 in steps of 10; or 200-100 in steps of -10; or a disparate set of numbers with varying size gaps and ordering like {100, 2, 2222, -63, 72}; etc.

Furthermore, see what happens with a `HashSet<String>` versus a `HashSet<Integer>`. You'll find the strings are ordered quite arbitrarily and rarely in order, I expect.